# How to hide keyboard after touch outside the textfield?

Tags: android, ios, angular, typescript, nativescript

I have a cross-platform app. I have a form that has more than one TextField. I want to hide the keyboard when the user touch outside of the textfield because it covers the button that sends the data.

How can I do?

In my .html file I have:

```
<ScrollView>
  <GridLayout ios:style="margin-top:50">
    <StackLayout class="form">

      <!-- Some TextView -->

    </StackLayout>
  </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**EDIT**

This is a [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=mRwOuh) that show the error.

Comment: Please show a little bit more effort. What have you done/tried? What exact error do you get? How does your code/html/xml look like?

Comment: I modified the question with more information and a Playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `tap` listener to your layout and hide keyboard using

**iOS**

```
import * as utils from "tns-core-modules/utils/utils";

UIApplication.sharedApplication
        .keyWindow
        .endEditing(true);
```

**Android**

```
utils.ad.dismissSoftInput();
```

**Edit**

You may simply call `dismissSoftInput()` method on the `TextField` if it's just one `TextField` in your `Page`. The above code helps if you have multiple `TextField`s on your `Page` and not sure which one is actually focused.

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=mRwOuh&v=4)

Comment: I have a form tha has more than one TextField. I add `<StackLayout class="form" (tap)="dismissKeyboard()">` in my .html file and in my .ts file I have a function called `dismissKeyboard()` that has the code you suggested but it gives 2 errors. the first one is `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'UIApplication'` and the second one is `ERROR TypeError: _co.dismissKeyboard is not a function`. How can I solve?

Comment: The first one sounds like a simple TypeScript error, either do `declare var UIApplication: any;` at top of your file Or install [tns-platform-declarations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations) plugin. Check yourself whether you have a method dismissKeyboard visible to the HTML component. If you still have issues, please share the Playground sample.

Comment: I solved this error `ERROR TypeError: _co.dismissKeyboard is not a function`, but I have another one. This is the [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=mRwOuh). It gives error with UIApplication

Comment: As I already mentioned in my above comment, `UIApplication` can be solved by a TS declaration. It's global class not member of your component. Also you should conditionally use the code on respective platform, updated [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=mRwOuh&v=3)

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand before. Thank you, now it works!

Comment: The tap event handler attached to the layout is firing when tapping the textfield:/

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to hide the keyboard in the latest version of NS 6.0+ is to directly access the context.

```
import { isIOS, isAndroid } from 'tns-core-modules/platform';
import * as utils from 'tns-core-modules/utils/utils';
declare const UIApplication;

  dismissKeyboard() {
    if (isIOS) {
      UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.endEditing(true);
    }
    if (isAndroid) {
      utils.ad.dismissSoftInput();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin:

```
yourTextView.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus -> if (!hasFocus) {
 //hide Keyboard
  }
}
```

Also make add to the parent layout 'focusableInTouchMode = true'  in the XML

Comment: Thank you, but it's not my case. I have a nativescript app

Comment: You have Android tagged in the question though?

Comment: Yes, but I need this feature for both android and ios

Answer (score 0):

In `Android` hide keyboard with:

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity mActivity) {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mActivity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not my case. I have a nativescript app.

Comment: Then you specified in your question!

Comment: Sorry! I modified the question.

Comment: @gsarme FYI, `utils.ad.dismissSoftInput();` does nothing but executes the same code as above internally, You can always access any native apis from NativeScript but with JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know